# What is the use of \SetAlgoLined in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I read in official documentation of algorithm2e that `\SetAlgoLined` is used to draw vertical lines between `begin` and `end` markers.

But without it also, there are vertical lines drawn, though there are no `begin` and `end` markers.

So, what exactly is the use of `\SetAlgoLined`?

Below is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{algo_issue}
\date{July 2022}

\usepackage{subcaption} %a
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}  %a
\usepackage{amsmath} % a
\usepackage{amsfonts} % a
\usepackage{amssymb} % a
\usepackage{amsthm} % a 2
\usepackage{multicol} % a
\usepackage{multirow} % a


% \SetKwInput{KwGlobal}{Global}              % Set the Global variables
\SetKwProg{myproc}{procedure}{}{end}  

\begin{document}

% \maketitle

\section{Introduction}
this is sample

\begin{algorithm*}[!htb]  % replaced [t] temporarliy [!htb]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \caption{ this is my caption }
    \label{algo:algo1}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    % \fontsize{8pt}{6pt}\selectfont
    \footnotesize
    %\small
    \SetAlgoLined
    

\myproc{$\mathtt{p1}${ ($a$, $b$, $c$)}} 
{
    hello
    hello 2
}

\end{multicols}
\end{algorithm*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Can you please show a minimal example of code?

Comment: @egreg Provided above; please help. You can comment \SetAlgoLined and observe the difference. Also the official document of algorithm2e says this:- ```\SetAlgoLined prints vertical lines between bloc start-end keywords as begin, end.```
The link to official doc is here:
```
http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf
```

Comment: You have the option `vlined`, don't you?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I have that option. If I remove both ```vlined``` and ```\SetAlgoLined``` still there are vertical lines. I am trying to understand the use of ```\SetAlgoLined``` and ```vlined```.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `algorithm2e` is not up-to-date. In the intentions of the authors, the default option should be `noline`, but it apparently isn't.

Use it explicitly. Of course you should remove `vlined` as well. You can then use `\SetAlgoLined` in the body of an `algorithm` environment where you want the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noline,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}


\SetKwProg{myproc}{procedure}{}{end}  

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm*}[!htbp]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{this is my caption}
  \label{algo:algo1}
  \myproc{$\mathtt{p1}(a,b,c)$}
   {
    hello
    hello 2
   }
\end{algorithm*}

\begin{algorithm*}[!htbp]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetAlgoLined
  \caption{this is my caption}
  \label{algo:algo2}
  \myproc{$\mathtt{p1}(a,b,c)$}
   {
    hello
    hello 2
   }
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or go to a different package, such as the combination `algorithm` and `algpseudocode`.